# How can I integrate a function scipy.sparse.linalg.eigs inside a tensorflow graph?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras

I would like to use the function eigs inside a tensorflow graph. I've tried wrapping it using tf.numpy_function. It works fine when I try it on a Tensor object that I created to check it, but I can't integrate it inside a tensorflow graph because I get the following error:

NotImplementedError: Cannot convert a symbolic Tensor (strided_slice:0) to a numpy array. This error may indicate that you're trying to pass a Tensor to a NumPy call, which is not supported.

Is there a workaround this?

Here is some code:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from scipy.sparse.linalg import eigs, eigsh
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input
```

```
dim = 10
A2 = np.zeros([1,dim**2,dim**2])
for l in range (0,dim):
    A2[0,l,l] = 1;
for l in range(dim**2-dim,dim**2):
    A2[0,l,l] = 1;
for l in range(dim,dim**2-dim):
    inc_c = np.mod(l,dim);
    if inc_c == 0 or inc_c == dim-1:
        A2[0,l,l] = 1;
    else:
        A2[0,l,l] = -4;
        A2[0,l,l-1] = 1;
        A2[0,l,l+1] = 1;
        A2[0,l,l-dim] = 1;
        A2[0,l,l+dim] = 1;

A3 = tf.convert_to_tensor(A2)
A3 = tf.concat([A3,A3],0)
```

```
def eigs1(x):
    lp,vp = eigs(x, k = 1,  which='SM')
    return np.reshape(vp,[vp.shape[1],vp.shape[0]])

def tf_eigs(x):
    ans = tf.TensorArray(tf.complex128, size=0, dynamic_size=True)
    for l in tf.range(0,tf.shape(x)[0]):
         ans = ans.write(l, tf.numpy_function(eigs1,[x[l,:,:]],tf.complex128))
    return tf.reshape(ans.stack(),[tf.shape(x)[0],tf.shape(x)[1]])
```

When I try the function on the tensor A3 that was created before I get a good result

```
v = tf_eigs(A3)

<tf.Tensor: shape=(2, 100), dtype=complex128, numpy=
array([[-1.00523628e-17+0.j, -3.22898077e-18+0.j, -2.51069177e-18+0.j,
         1.55893560e-18+0.j, -6.93016758e-18+0.j, -3.52605333e-18+0.j,
        -2.60820056e-18+0.j, -3.06640753e-17+0.j, -2.08008623e-17+0.j,

...
```

But when I try to include it inside a graph I get the error

```
input_shape = (dim**2,dim**2)
input1 = Input(shape=input_shape,batch_size=2,dtype = tf.complex128)
outputs = tf_eigs(input1)

NotImplementedError: Cannot convert a symbolic Tensor (strided_slice:0) to a numpy array. This error may indicate that you're trying to pass a Tensor to a NumPy call, which is not supported
```

Is there a workaround? Thx

Edit : Full Traceback

```
NotImplementedError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-e7545be42415> in <module>
      1 input_shape = (dim**2,dim**2)
      2 input1 = Input(shape=input_shape,batch_size=2,dtype = tf.complex128)
----> 3 outputs = tf_eigs(input1)

<ipython-input-3-fd7ecebb6b7f> in tf_eigs(x)
      7     #while_condition = lambda l: tf.less(l, x.shape[0])
      8     for l in tf.range(0,tf.shape(x)[0]):
----> 9          ans = ans.write(l, tf.numpy_function(eigs1,[x[l,:,:]],tf.complex128))
     10     return tf.reshape(ans.stack(),[tf.shape(x)[0],tf.shape(x)[1]])
     11 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/dispatch.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    199     """Call target, and fall back on dispatchers if there is a TypeError."""
    200     try:
--> 201       return target(*args, **kwargs)
    202     except (TypeError, ValueError):
    203       # Note: convert_to_eager_tensor currently raises a ValueError, not a

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/script_ops.py in numpy_function(func, inp, Tout, name)
    630     Single or list of `tf.Tensor` which `func` computes.
    631   """
--> 632   return py_func_common(func, inp, Tout, stateful=True, name=name)
    633 
    634 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/script_ops.py in py_func_common(func, inp, Tout, stateful, name)
    517   """
    518   if context.executing_eagerly():
--> 519     result = func(*[np.array(x) for x in inp])
    520     result = nest.flatten(result)
    521 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/script_ops.py in <listcomp>(.0)
    517   """
    518   if context.executing_eagerly():
--> 519     result = func(*[np.array(x) for x in inp])
    520     result = nest.flatten(result)
    521 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py in __array__(self)
    846         "Cannot convert a symbolic Tensor ({}) to a numpy array."
    847         " This error may indicate that you're trying to pass a Tensor to"
--> 848         " a NumPy call, which is not supported".format(self.name))
    849 
    850   def __len__(self):

NotImplementedError: Cannot convert a symbolic Tensor (strided_slice_2:0) to a numpy array. This error may indicate that you're trying to pass a Tensor to a NumPy call, which is not supported
```

Comment: Are you clear about the difference between the Symbolic tensor and the A3 type of tensor?  You may need to do some more basic reading in the tensorflow docs.

Comment: I do understand (I think) the difference between the two. I was trying to illustrate with an example of what I'm trying to do. So yes, the question could be how to can we build this function for Symbolic tensors.

Comment: Is that the full traceback?

Comment: I've added the full traceback now, thx